# Python NLP, Neural Network, text clustering

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nltk, gensim

Edit: I'm asking this because I've spent over 40 hours experimenting with these packages, and feel as though I've gotten nowhere.

I'm pretty new to Python. I've done a RandomForestClassifier model successfully at my organization and the model is in production, but neural nets are beyond my current comprehension.

I'm working on a text classification problem in Python. I had 243 samples (rows) that are taken from 25 job postings. I have one column that is the string sentence, and one column that is the job posting that it came from.

I'm gunning for a promotion at work, and thought this would be a neat opportunity to learn about neural networks. (I'm not going for a data scientist-type role, this just fascinates me.) Each sample is one "job duty" from a job posting, and each "document" is a job posting. One job posting could have multiple duties that are nearly identical, every job posting should have 2-3 identical (abstracted) duties, and ultimately, I assume there will be 15-20 clusters of "duties" from my 25 job postings.

Essentially, my desired output is to classify each row (regardless of which job posting it came from; I don't think my document column is relevant) to n clusters. I don't expect labels for my clusters.

I've cleaned my 243 samples; removing punctuation and stopwords, and have it in a dataframe.

The packages I've experimented with so far are Keras, doc2vec, word2vec, nltk, and Soundex

1. Is there a way to cluster my samples (unsupervised) without training data?
2. Do I need to upload a corpus to train? Does a corpus by default have classification labels?
3. What is the simplest (willing to sacrifice accuracy) to get n clusters out of 243 samples (I will go through the contents of each cluster and determine the label for the cluster post-processing)

Just some vaguely directional guidance would really help me.

Comment: Questions of the form:  "How do I analyze data" are going to be too broad for Stack Overflow.  There may be other forums where you can get such advice.

Comment: That's a valid point. This isn't so much "How do I analyze data" - I spend 50 hours a week doing that. I'm more looking for directional approach to NN/NLP.

Answer (score 0):

As someone who does this for a living,

> 40 hours experimenting with these packages

may not be enough.

Things you need to know:

- Natural language processing (NLP)
- Machine learning

Unfornatlety, throwing packages at your data will not solve your problem.

Now to answer your questions:

#### 1. Is there a way to cluster my samples (unsupervised) without training data?

Yes.

1. Get **features** from your text. You should know what features are important.
2. Run one of the algorithms from here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#clustering

#### 2. Do I need to upload a corpus to train? Does a corpus by default have classification labels?

- What do you want to train?
- "Corpus" means a set of texts. *Any* collection of texts can be a corpus. A corpus does not necessarily have classification labels.

#### 3. What is the simplest (willing to sacrifice accuracy) to get n clusters out of 243 samples (I will go through the contents of each cluster and determine the label for the cluster post-processing)

See question 1.

Based on your questions, I'm assuming, you are new to the domain of NLP. I would suggest you talk to someone in person who knows NLP.